# Autocapitalize of keyboard depends on pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working for a mobile web application.
Here is a scenario where the patter of input field is "A-B"

```
    <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" class="inputTextCenter" maxlength="1" oninput="if      (this.value.length > this.maxLength) {this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);}" pattern="A-B" tabindex="5" style="height: 21px; width: 16px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
```

so , if user has to enter anything he will have to capitalize the keybord,then only he will be able to enter anything.

Is there any solution in javascript through which the small latter automatically coverts into capital,when user enter small latter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the CSS property `text-transform: capitalize;` Note: this will not capitalize the value itself. If you also want the value to be uppercase you can do this on the change handler: `this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an onChange handler and read the value from the input. Then capitalize the value with value.toUpperCase() and stick it back to the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>A function is triggered when the user releases a key in the input field. The function transforms the character to upper case.</p>
    Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("fname");
        x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
    }
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```